# assets in the vendor directory not loading with require_tree in Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, asset-pipeline

I'm using Rails 3.2.9. I have some Javascript/jQuery libraries I use, so I placed them in `/app/assets/javascripts`. They automatically load and everything works fine because I have the following manifest in `application.js`:

```
//= require_tree .
```

But then I read I should be putting these things in `/vendor/assets/javascripts`. That directory is created, but empty, by default. So I moved my 3rd party libraries there. I can access them with `http://0.0.0.0:3000/assets/jquery.qtip.min.js`, for example. However, they are not included in every webpage now. It seems `require_tree .` needs a little more help to include vendor javascripts.

What's the proper way to include 3rd party javascript/jQuery libraries in Rails?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `application.js` file, you should add `//= require filename`. Example, I have a file called `jquery.markitup.js` in my `vendor/assets/javascripts/`, so this is how i added it:

```
...
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require jquery.markitup
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: You shouldn't have to specify particular files unless order matters. require_tree . is supposed to include everything in all the asset folders recursively (e.g. app/assets, lib/assets, vendor/assets)